# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker is not working in IIS Host

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the following code to authenticate to Google using the Google .Net client library
Im using this code:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("");
            string fileName = string.Format(".credentials/calendar-{0}", strLoginName);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, fileName);
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
        }
```

I am using my own client id and client secret key. This code is perfectly working when I am running from visual studio, but is not working from after hosted in IIS.
it have exception

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=100583113105-3duloq0e8j9o6aapc035grmvo9j2chtv.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1:61158%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar" for authorization. See inner exception for details. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at DataHandler.GoogleCalendar.SyncCalendar(NameValueCollection parameters)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=100583113105-3duloq0e8j9o6aapc035grmvo9j2chtv.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2F127.0.0.1:61158%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar" for authorization. See inner exception for details. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()<---

How can i fix it??

Comment: I have the same issue, have you found the answer?